# Query speed improvement (opening stock, running stock and closing stock)

Tags: performance, firebird, query-performance

I have a table (refer to below structure) where I track all stock ins and outs. Now I want to generate a report from this table to find the **opening_stock, purchased, purchased_return, sales, sales_returned, damaged_inventory** based on provided date range.

Query:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID,  

(SELECT (SUM(PURCHASE_QUANTITY) - SUM(SALE_QUANTITY)) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE < '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID) AS OPENING
, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(PURCHASE_QUANTITY), 0) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID AND REF_TYPE = 'PURCHASE') AS PURCHASE
, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SALE_QUANTITY), 0) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID AND REF_TYPE = 'PURCHASE RETURN') AS PURCHASE_RETURN
, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SALE_QUANTITY),0) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID AND REF_TYPE = 'SALE') AS SALE
, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(PURCHASE_QUANTITY), 0) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID AND REF_TYPE = 'SALE RETURN') AS SALE_RETURN
, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SALE_QUANTITY), 0) FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '2019-09-31' AND ITEM_ID = l.ITEM_ID AND REF_TYPE = 'DMG') AS DAMAGED_INVENTORY
FROM INV_ITEM_LEDGER l
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

When I run this query on **47,619** records (Total current queries), the system hangs and stops responding.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE INV_ITEM_LEDGER (
  ITEM_LEDGER_ID     INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  ITEM_ID            INTEGER,
  REF_ID             INTEGER,
  REF_TYPE           VARCHAR(20),
  PURCHASE_QUANTITY  DECIMAL(18,4),
  SALE_QUANTITY      DECIMAL(18,4),
  DESCRIPTION        VARCHAR(512),
  BATCH_NO           VARCHAR(20),
  EXPIRY             VARCHAR(20),
  STOCK_ID           INTEGER,
  BRANCH_CODE        VARCHAR(20),
  LAST_SYNCED        VARCHAR(20),
  ENTRY_DATE         VARCHAR(20),
  LAST_UPDATED       VARCHAR(20),
  ENTRY_DATE2        VARCHAR(20),
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_LEDGER_ID)
);

CREATE INDEX INV_ITEM_LEDGER_INDEX01
  ON INV_ITEM_LEDGER
  (ITEM_LEDGER_ID, ITEM_ID);
```

Is there anything to enhance the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index on (item_id, ref_type, entry_date) is mandatory in this case. This would avoid creating a temporary table for the group by:

```
    CREATE INDEX INV_ITEM_LEDGER_INDEX02
    ON INV_ITEM_LEDGER
    (ITEM_ID, REF_TYPE, ENTRY_DATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you can rewrite this to a conditional aggregation for each time range (before 2019-09-31 and after). Typically a "plain" aggregation is faster then multiple scalar sub-queries.

```sql
SELECT l.item_id, 
       l.opening, 
       x.purchase, 
       x.purchase_return,
       x.sale,
       x.sale_return,
       x.damaged_inventory
FROM (
  -- aggregate items before 2019-09-31
  SELECT item_id, 
         sum(purchase_quantity) - sum(sale_quantity) as opening, 
  FROM inv_item_ledger
  WHERE entry_date < '2019-09-31'
  GROUP BY ITEM_ID              
) l
  JOIN (
    -- calculate the conditional aggregates for rows after 2019-09-31
    SELECT item_id, 
           sum(CASE WHEN ref_type = 'PURCHASE' THEN purchase_quantity END) as purchase,
           sum(CASE WHEN ref_type = 'PURCHASE RETURN' THEN sale_quantity END) as purchase_return,
           sum(CASE WHEN ref_type = 'SALE' THEN sale_quantity END) as sale,
           sum(CASE WHEN ref_type = 'SALE RETURN' THEN purchase_quantity END) as sale_return,
           sum(CASE WHEN ref_type = 'DMG' THEN sale_quantity END) as damaged_inventory
    FROM inv_item_ledger
    WHERE entry_date >= '2019-09-31'
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID   
  ) x ON x.Item_id = l.item_id
```

This uses the fact that aggregate functions (like `sum()`) ignore NULL values. The CASE expression inside the sum() function only returns a value if the `ref_type` of that row matches, and NULL for all others.

Comment: Thanks, but it will only `sum` only for dates < '2019-09-31', while I want *opening* before '2019-09-31' and others after '2019-09-31'.

Comment: @0_0: ah, I didn't see that. But you can split it up into two queries - which should still be better than 6

Comment: I am using fastreport with delphi and merging them back in the delphi would be another performance issue. (I might need many nested loops). but I will give it a try

Comment: Why would you need to "merge" anything back? That is a single query that should return the same result as your existing query.

Comment: never mind, I didn't check your answer and I was thinking to run 2 separate quires. but still my code runs faster than your code :D.